# why we only have a approximation for every circumference for ellipse but not define a special formula for each ellipse

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

Why do we only have an approximation for every circumference for ellipse, but we cannot define a special ratio formula for each ellipse? Is it possible for people to use a computer to find the exact "infinite series" relationship between the circumference of the ellipse and the major axis and minor axis?

Comment: We need an approximation for computing the circumference of a circle too, as $\pi$ isn't rational...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).  Series for it are well-known, and many numerical analysis packages or languages like *Mathematica* provide them as a function call.

Comment: Indeed, I believe the reason the "elliptic integrals" were originally given that name is this problem.  Arc length for an ellipse was--at least at that time--the best-known example of such an integral.

Comment: For the series written down, see "Circumference" here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Mathematical_definitions_and_properties

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, the algorithm for computing the circumference of an ellipse (based on the [arithmetic-geometric mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-GeometricMean.html)) isn't too long if your environment doesn't support computing the complete elliptic integral of the second kind, $E(m)$:

```
ellipseCircumference[a_, b_] := Module[{f = 1, s, v = (1 + b/a)/2, w},
   w = (1 - (b/a)^2)/(4 v);
   s = v^2;
   While[True,
    v = (v + Sqrt[(v - w) (v + w)])/2;
    w = (w/2)^2/v;
    f *= 2; s -= f w^2;
    If[Abs[w] < 10^(-Precision[{a, b}]), Break[]];
    ];
   2 a Pi s/v
   ] /; Precision[{a, b}] < Infinity && Positive[a] && Positive[b]
```

(Yes, I'm using *Mathematica*. Yes, I know *Mathematica* has `EllipticE[]` available. I'm only using *Mathematica* for illustrative purposes. ;) )

Compare:

```
N[ellipseCircumference[3, 2], 20]
15.865439589290589791

With[{a = 3, b = 2}, N[4 a EllipticE[1 - (b/a)^2], 20]]
15.865439589290589791
```