# Calculate perimeter from parametric form with an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

Suppose I have a thing such as an ellipse:

$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^{2}=1$$

now we can define it so that $\frac{x}{a}=cos(\theta)$ and $\frac{y}{b}=sin(\theta)$. I know the perimeter formula

$$\mu(S)=\int\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^{2}} dx.$$

It is easy to paramerize the ellipse but how can I parametrize the perimeter formula so that I can easily calculate the perimeter?

I find that I am doing things the hard way like this:

$$y=\pm b \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2}}$$

now if I plug in the y into the formula of perimeter, it is messy. Can I do it elegantly with parametric form somehow?

Comment: I gave a mention of, and an algorithm for, the complete elliptic integral in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73472).

Comment: possible duplicate of [why we only have a approximation for every circumference for ellipse but not define a special formula for each ellipse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73472/why-we-only-have-a-approximation-for-every-circumference-for-ellipse-but-not-def)

Comment: If there would be a simple formula for the perimeter of an ellipse you would have met it in high school $\ldots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write the following

$$ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta$$

and so

$$P=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta$$

and this is just an elliptic integral. The final result takes the form ($b>a$)

$$P=4bE(e)$$

being

$$E(e)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

and $e^2=1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ the eccentricity.

Comment: ...I have never really understoond what the $S$ here means? In physics, it sometimes denotes some surface $S$ but here it is? Do you change the coordinates somehow and use the Jacobian matrix or something like that, sorry thinking alound (maybe totally skewed wrong ideas)...

Comment: @hhh: it's the differential corresponding to arclength.

Comment: @J.M.: yes but what is is $S$? It is a partial derivative apparently, there is something I cannot grap in the very beginning of this answer -- chain rule ...have to calculate... thinking still aloud...

Comment: @hhh: I see an $s$, not an $S$. (Capitalization matters, see.) $s$ is a conventional symbol for arclength. $\mathrm ds$ is a differential ($\mathrm d$) for arclength ($s$). Crystal?

Comment: @hhh: It is just Pythagorean theorem as you take small lengths $dx$ and $dy$ and so your infinitesimal arc length is $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dY^2}$. Then, you sum all of them. In your case, you have to consider that $dx=x'(\theta)d\theta$ and  $dy=y'(\theta)d\theta$ and you are done.

Comment: @J.M.: I am on it (sorry my book messed up with capitalization), have to reread this stuff after this info -- I think this infinitesimal thing will make the book easier to understand, I thought that I had to do some sort of coordinate transformation...

Comment: If we have $x=a\cos\theta$ and $y=b\sin\theta$ as in OP and $a\geq b$ (major axis on $x$ axis, length $2a$), then $e^2=1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$ and $P=4aE(e)$; cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Eccentricity & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference. So in general, $e^2=\frac{|a^2-b^2|}{\max(a,b)^2}$ and $P=4\max(a,b)E(e)$. @hhh: $s$ is arc length, i.e. the length traversed along the portion of curve parametrized in the integral.

Comment: @bgins: Yes, I have chosen $b>a$.

Comment: @Jon: If $b>a$ then I think $e^2=1-(\frac{a}{b})^2$, not $(\frac{b}{a})^2-1$, and $P=4bE(e)$. In know it's kind of trivial but maybe it helps prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: @bgins: Thank you a lot. I will fix this mistake.

Comment: I am missing one 2 somewhere, I get $2b$. By symetry, I get one two by dividing the $\pi/2$ but one 2 missing still, ideas?

Comment: @hhh: Indeed, the initial integral goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ but the elliptic integral is given between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The factor 4 comes out as you need four times the elliptic integral.