# Set up integral of arclength of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, arc-length

I search up this rather common question but I never found an exact answer. For my Calculus 2 class, I need to "set up the integral that represents the arc length of the ellipse and simplify the integrand." 
Here's what I've done so far: 
[image]

I used parametric equations (not sure if that's the right thing to do), but I have no idea how to substitute the upper and lower limit of the integral. I don't quite understand how the upper/lower limit works(beta and alpha on the picture) since there seems to be two variables here (I didn't learned multivariable yet).

Can someone help me with this assignment?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108199/arc-length-of-an-ellipse-using-integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The written formula for arc length is correct. Parametrizing the ellipse as you did 
$$
(x(t),y(t))=(a\cos t,b\sin t)
$$
you need $t\in [0,2\pi)$ to plot sketch the curve of the ellipse once (think in analogy to the circle). This gives you your lower bound, 0, and upper bound $2\pi$.

Comment: Is there really no way to obtain the upper/lower limit by algebraic way (like U-sub, you change the upper and lower limit for each sub accordingly).

Comment: @YouXiaoRuan But when you substitute, you have an integral to start with. Here you're trying to come up with an integral.

Comment: I got it, but would it be much more complicated if we want to calculate a specific arc length of the ellipse?

Comment: @YouXiaoRuan there is no closed form expression for arc length on an ellipse. Area is easy, not perimeter.